# Ubuntu CLI: Nested For Loops Output

Tags: for-loop, ubuntu

So I am trying to do a nested for loop on the CLI on an Ubuntu based computer. I've got the loop working, mostly. This is a gist of what I'm inputting:

```
for i in $(seq 6 1 8)
do
for j in $(seq 0.80 0.05 0.95)
do
<cmd> input_directory out$i_put$j .......
done
done
```

So the command I'm using puts files in a directory with the name out$i_put$j.. ideally. What I end up with instead is a directory with the name out$j (Substituting j for whatever value it's on). Because it's important to keep these files organized, I need the distinction from $i and $j. Is there a syntax I should be using to accomplish this? I haven't been able to find this online.

Comment: Try `out${i}_put${j}`.

Comment: You mean the shell. The command line is what you are typing into.